# what is the meaning of a phrase " Or so some have argued" in the following sentence?

Tags: phrases

they do not expect to learn something about the nature of
morality itself. If you want to know what makes wrong acts wrong, ask a
moral philosopher, not a psychologist. Or so some have argued.

Comment: At least that's what some people say.

Answer (score 1):

*Or so* is an expression that generally means *approximately*. In this context, it's actually very similar in meaning to the phrases *or something to that effect* and *at least*. *At least* fits the meaning best here. *Some* is a pronoun that refers to an unspecified number or amount of people or things. Now, it's not that hard to take it from here and figure out what that sentence really says: at least that's what some people have argued.